# accessing dojo attach point outside templated widget

Tags: dojo, ibm-mobilefirst

I have a dojo attach point for list item which is inside a templated widget.I need to  access the dojo attach point outside the widget in order to assign onclick to the list item created by the template.How do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you want to attach an event handler to it, you have to provide a function. You can override functions/properties from outside using getters and setters.

I also suggest using `data-dojo-attach-event` if you only need the node for attaching event handlers. For example by using: `data-dojo-attach-event="onclick: myFunction"`. By doing this, it needs a function called `myFunction` in your templated widget, provide a default function (in your widget) for example:

```js
myFunction: function() {
    /** Stub */
},
```

And then you can do something like this from outside:

```js
myWidget.set("myFunction", function(evt) {
     console.log("Someone clicked on the list item");
});
```

Because the `myFunction` event handler is overriden, it will execute the function provided in the setter.

You could also directly access the attach points from outside using:

```
myWidget.listItemNode
```

When you have a `data-dojo-attach-point="listItemNode"`. However, I don't think it's recommended to use it this way because now your widget is tightly coupled (you use the internal functionality of the widget).

Comment: Instead of *replacing* the original myFunction, you can also use [`dojo/aspect`](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/aspect.html) to *add* behavior without affecting its default implementation.

Comment: That's also a possibility, but I usually have a function called `_myFunction` with the default implementation and `myFunction` which can be overriden. In my example I'm showing a case where the `myFunction` is a part of the public API which may be overridden.

Answer (score 0):

```
HTML template:-
 <div data-dojo-attach-point="infoDialog" >
 </div> 
Save this as "Template.html"
---------------------------------------------
load this html file using "dojo\text" plugin in your widget i.e.  
"dojo/text!./templates/Template.html",
and store as template in widget main function 
-----------------------------------------------
assign it as template string to the widget.

templateString: template,

now this template attachpoint(infoDialog) will be the part of your current widget scope.
-----------------------------------------------
attach event:-

this.infoDialog.onclick=function(){
   alert("hello world")
};
```

Comment: Is this a good way of using the nodes? By using it this way you're depending on the template of a widget from **outside** the widget. So in fact you're using the internal API of the widget. That makes your widget tightly coupled to the other script using the attach point while you should strive for a loosely coupled design.